# Echo Variable inside of echo statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo a php variable inside of a php echo statement.

I have a column in a MySql database called `display_code` which contains a value such as `$num_rows_customers`.

I am calling this from the DB as `displayCode`

```
$displayCode = $row ['display_code'];
```

And trying to echo like this:

```
 <?php    
           echo "<div class='col-md-3'>
           $displayCode
           </div>";

 ?>
```

However this is printing `$num_rows_customers` instead of a number

Is there a way to do this?

By the way, I already have this script on the page

```
<?php $result100=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers")or die('Error 27' . mysql_error());
$num_rows_customers = mysql_num_rows($result100);?>
```

Comment: `$diDplay`? Really?

Comment: Oops, changed in the question (It's correct on my script)

Comment: How did you define `$displayCode` variable?

Comment: @u_mulder - what do you mean? I have added `$num_rows_customers` to the column in the DB?

Comment: Sorry, I have called from the DB... `$displayCode = $row ['display_code'];`

Comment: Thanks, the answer below works great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About Variable variables read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
$displayCode = 'num_rows_customers';
$num_rows_customers = 10;  
           echo "<div class='col-md-3'>
           {$$displayCode}
           </div>";
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/610622)**

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!